# Обособление приложений

Tags: пунктуация

Можно ли первое приложение обособить с помощью запятых?

8 октября в рамках IV Международного газового форума компания (...) совместно с мировым лидером по производству оборудования для газонаполнительных станций - компанией (...)- провели встречу со студентами Санкт-Петербургского Горного университета — старейшего технического ВУЗа России.

Answer (score 1):

А какое именно предложение Вы хотите обособить? У Вас верно расставлены знаки препинания, и запятые тут не нужны. Только вот "вуз" пишется строчными буквами - эта аббревиатура давно вошла в речь, поэтому нет нужды выделять ее прописными.

Comment: Первое. Совместно с лидером, компанией... хотелось бы узнать, можно ли здесь поставить запятые?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, здесь можно обособить и с помощью запятых, если вы приведете весь контекст: какое предложение следует после "компаний". Так трудно сказать. Обычно приложение обособляется при помощи тире, если оно носит пояснительный характер. В этом случае перед приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слово "а именно". Подробнее можете ознакомиться здесь: [Справочник по правописанию и стилистике](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Byandsearch%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=486.qjhVimwkghY9bE0XA_y4MimDXHPNQBr2clmgxE9sv9kf45YMLrHF5v1zyP05olG5KkFZymx6EQf5blSqgJAC0jqUHgaADxIumvf5FgAo9Do2pbUXw1NBHynkjhdKawGayErpduPkKyN2DSp-ef2z8_6XamMmTSjYpeJ_EdxAu9ZSpK7kgk5ikAvjN3deIg5wPylv-5kbhv0U6izO2lajpg.f6f40e793732ae1c11ea405507a9aeacc8315840&uuid=&state=AiuY0DBWFJ4ePaEse6rgeAjgs2pI3DW9Iuwyq9ogZlIHwdW66mTRJqRBwWr3dH1qyPIFFbBipYj4smz5HXXShKeKNCqWZx-IHNWXoPZbxcu_dxE5IxtqE6n-VR_N2WQeXPV4mMIXjJkMriX98ivyQqGxJ5KzwMv3__AGCx0xEbgHGEZuQCyemnesYBJGWkiWrIYE1TIWjzJsWICGLZPCX1P4ranQ1fn7qTUSiIlCzpd6u0V-hBTGr663FCwKDK8k&data=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&b64e=2&sign=27f876f495948fb2813b186215761164&keyno=0&l10n=ru&cts=1414071382228&mc=1.584962500721156).